# Create numpy array with proper step and step range

Tags: arrays, numpy

Hi all I need to create specific array contains random integers from certain range with step.

Output need to by like this:

```
[[0 3 2 1]
 [1 2 0 3]
 [2 0 3 1]
    ...
 [10 7 8 9]]
```

First digit in each row need to be a certain value `[0,1,2,...]`
next 3 digits in the row need to be random from range `(0,3)` for first row (without 0), `(0,3)` for the second (without 1), `(6,10)` for last one (without 10). Generally (x, y) without fixed digit where x = fixed number - 4 but not less than the fixed number, y = fixed number + 4 but not more than the fixed number .

Range of random numbers need to be 4 digits without repeats in certain direction.

Another visualization:
fixed numbers = [0,1,2,3,..]
random range = (0,3) + offset

```
            array              range - without

[[0, random numbers in range]  (0,3) - 0
 [1, random numbers in range]  (0,3) - 1
 [2, random numbers in range]  (0,3) - 2
       ...
 [6, random numbers in range]  (2,6) - 6
 [7, random numbers in range]  (3,7) - 7
       ...
 [n, random numbers in range]]  (n-4,n) - n
```

After some manipulations i wrote below code, which is pretty fast but i think that it can by done much better and faster.

```
def winning_matrix():
    ######## create beginning 4 vector array ########
    # create vector with counts to merge
    add_vector_beginning = np.arange(4)[:, None]
    # create zeros array for data input
    add_array = np.zeros(shape=(4, 3))
    # fill up add array
    add_array[0] = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    add_array[1] = np.array([0, 2, 3])
    add_array[2] = np.array([0, 1, 3])
    add_array[3] = np.array([0, 1, 2])
    # convert array values to integers
    add_array = add_array.astype(int)

    # mix array values
    mix_array = np.zeros(shape=(4, 3))
    for i in range(4):
         mix_array[i] = np.random.choice(add_array[i], replace=False, size=3)
    # convert array values to integers
    mix_array_int = mix_array.astype(int)
    # merge array with proper vector
    add_matrix = np.column_stack((add_vector_beginning, mix_array_int))
    #### create main winning array #######
    # create add vector with proper count values
    add_vector = np.arange(vectors_number - 4)[:, None] + 4
    # create offset for main array
    offset = np.arange(vectors_number - 4)[:, None] + 1
    # create random array
    winning_matrix_random = np.random.rand(vectors_number - 4, 3)
    # convert random array values in array into positions intigers
    winning_convert = winning_matrix_random.argsort(1)
    # add offset to array
    winning_matrix_raw = winning_convert + offset
    # merge add vector with winning array
    winning_matrix = np.column_stack((add_vector, winning_matrix_raw))

    #### merge two created arrays into one #########
    for i in range(4):
         winning_matrix = np.insert(winning_matrix, i, add_matrix[i], axis=0)
    return winning_matrix
```

Any suggestions how to speed up?

Comment: You are leaving out exactly the interesting part where `3<n<6`.

Comment: fast typing, already corrected

Comment: So "random" basically means that their order is random?

Comment: Stefan,  "Yes" random numbers = [3,2,1] or [2,1,3]

Comment: that's not random, that's shuffled. Random would be `[3,3,1],[1,1,1],...`

Comment: Let's call the fixed number `z`, then `x=z-4,y=z+4` but x should not be less than `z` and `y` should not be more than `z`, so `x=y=z`. Please come up with a consistent algorithm so we can help you.

Comment: anishtain4, i mean random with no repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the choices for each line are independent, depending on a `n` parameter (or two).  If so I'd focus on writing a function that generates one row given `n`.

For that row, generate a range, e.g. `x = np.arange(m, m+4)`, remove `n`, then do a `np.random.choise(x, size=3, replace=False)`.   I haven't read your description with enough care to get all the details.

Then just run this function for each row, accumulating the results in a list.

```
def arow(n,m,k=4):
    x = list(range(m,m+k))
    i = x.pop(x.index(n))
    y = np.random.choice(x, replace=False, size=3)
    y = [i]+y.tolist()
    return y

In [34]: arow(0,0,4)
Out[34]: [0, 1, 2, 3]
In [35]: arow(1,0,4)
Out[35]: [1, 2, 3, 0]
In [39]: arow(10,7,4)
Out[39]: [10, 8, 7, 9]

In [47]: k=4
    ...: alist = []
    ...: for n in range(11):
    ...:     m = max(0,n-k+1)
    ...:     r = arow(n,m,k)
    ...:     alist.append(r)
    ...: np.array(alist)

Out[47]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  3,  1],
       [ 1,  0,  3,  2],
       [ 2,  3,  1,  0],
       [ 3,  1,  2,  0],
       [ 4,  3,  2,  1],
       [ 5,  4,  3,  2],
       [ 6,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 7,  6,  4,  5],
       [ 8,  7,  6,  5],
       [ 9,  8,  6,  7],
       [10,  8,  9,  7]])
```

Comment: Thank You, that will do the trick :). Is there a faster solution to do this? I need to create array with over 10**6 rows in each loop in my main program. Now time to do this is over 50 seconds.